# How to save an indexPath in a user default and how to have a cell in a tableview pre-selected as it is loaded? (xcode 8, swift 3.0)

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, nsuserdefaults

So I have been looking all over the internet for an answer to this but to no avail. Basically, I have code to have cells in a tableview have a check mark when selected, which works fine. However, when selected, I want the indexPath to be saved in a user default so that the next time the user views it, that particular cell that she had selected before can be pre-selected:

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    if let cell = tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath) {
        cell.accessoryType = .checkmark
        UserDefaults.standard.set(indexPath as IndexPath, forKey: "OnHomeShow")
    }

}

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didDeselectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    if let cell = tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath) {
        cell.accessoryType = .none
    }

}
```

The saving in the user default didn't work! Anyone able to help? Furthermore, how do I get it so that I can have a pre-selected cell? I used this code here:

```
    override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    if let x = UserDefaults.standard.object(forKey: "OnHomeShow") as? IndexPath
    {
        //I want to pre-select the cell set by the user-default
    }
    else
    {
        //I want to pre-select the first cell
    }
}
```

But I have no idea what code to put to select a cell programmatically! Anyone know how to help? Thanks!

Comment: Have you read the documentation for `UserDefaults`? Notice what is says about the types of objects you can store.

Comment: Try `tableView.select​Row(at:​animated:​scroll​Position:​)` to set the selection.

Comment: @rmaddy oh, so you can't save that in UserDefaults? How would I be able to store the information of a specific cell then?

Comment: You just need to save the section and the row. `UserDefaults.standard.set(indexPath.section, forKey: "section")` and to read `UserDefaults.standard.integer(forKey: "section")`

Comment: If all your Indexes are at section 0 just save the row

Comment: @LeoDabus oh, I see, thanks! Would I be able to convert that to indexPath to input into `tableView.select​Row(at:​animated:​scroll​Position:​)`?

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/reference/foundation/indexpath/1779555-init

Comment: The UserDefaults does not persist unless you call synchronise(). Call UserDefaults.standard.synchronize() after UserDefaults.standard.set(indexPath as IndexPath, forKey: "OnHomeShow")

Comment: @ubiAle this is not true. No need to force sync at all. Actually you won't need 99% of the time